# android kotlin retrofit2 multipart file upload is success but the file is corrupted

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I have a requirement to upload pptx/pdf from the device to server.
I am using retrofit2 - multipart to upload file.

when I upload file, the request is getting success and the content is uploaded. But when I am trying to access the file, it says file is corrupted.

Below is my code:
val f = File(filePath)

val name = f.name

val requestBody = f.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())

val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Attachment",f.name,requestBody)

```
@Multipart
@Headers("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type: application/json")  
@POST("web/lists/getByTitle('Ideas_2021')/items({ideaId})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{fileName}')")
suspend fun uploadIdeaAttachmentAsMultipart(@Header("Cookie") objCookie : String, @Header("X-RequestDigest") xReqDigest : String, @Path("ideaId") ideaId : Int, @Path("fileName") fileName : String, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part) : Response<IdeaAttachmentResponse>
```

Could anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not confuse the server telling that json is coming which isn't the case.

Comment: I tried without "Content-Type: application/json" as well, but getting the same issue.

Comment: Which content type did you use now? Also tell file size in bytes of original and copy.

Comment: I have removed "Content-Type: application/json" from the headers. file size is 723kb (both original and copy.).   I extracted the file to my macbook and tried opening with MSOffice, is says "PowerPoint found a problem with content in ZipIdeation_Template.pptx.
PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation.
If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair."  After I select repair, it opens the document.

Comment: But in my requirement, I have to show the document in webview within the application, which is not able to open the corrupted file. it says "officeImportErrorDomain error 912"

Comment: `file size is 723kb`. In amount of bytes please. Not in KB. Every byte counts.

Comment: `have removed "Content-Type: application/json" from the headers. ` Yes i knew that already. You told that before. But you should have supplied a different content type. Which one?

Comment: Not providing any type now. Read somewhere that for multipart we should not provide content type, not sure how true it is.

Comment: So you will not report file sizes in bytes.

Comment: Content-Length 708332

Comment: ????? I asked for a file size before upload. And after upload a file size of the file on the server. What you do in between is irrelevant at the moment. We want to see first if the amount of bytes is equal. Compare the sizes! I asked that 12 hours ago already.

Comment: @blackapps file size is same before and after upload. i.e. on the device and on the server.